# If I stub out .save method in my controller test how can I check the correct show template is rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am trying to test a controller create method in a rails app using RSpec as shown below:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
     redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
  else
     render new_user_path
     flash[:error] = "User not saved"
  end
end
```

However if i stub out `.new` to prevent the test from using Active Record and the User model by forcing it to return `true` the **id** of the `@user` is not set by `.save` as normal so I cannot test for it redirecting to `user_path(@user.id)` as `@user.id` is nil

Here is my initial test for RSpec:

```
it "creates a user and redirects" do
  expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:save).and_return(true) 
  post :create, { user: {name: "John", username: "Johnny98", email: "johnny98@example.com"} }

  expect(assigns(:user).name).to eq("John")
  expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(assigns(:user))
end
```

How should I test for this redirect in RSpec.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would using FactoryGirl solve the issue with the id not being set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use mocks - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs.

```
user = double("user", id: 1, save: true)
```

Then you should mock you method with double you've just created

```
expect(User).to receive(:new).and_return(user)
```

And then test redirect.

```
expect(response).to redirect_to user_path(user)
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Why would you expect `.save` to return a `user` instance? This method returns `true` or `false` actually.

Comment: Also there is no expectation for the user to receive the '.save' method in your example is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. First of all #save is stubbed when we define double. And second is the golden rule: one spec, one expectation. If you want to test user saving that should be separate test.

Comment: You should have trouble passing your double to `user_path` like that, since they respond very different to a `to_param` call. More on that [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way:

```
  it 'should redirect to a user if save returned true' do
    @user_instance = double
    @user_id = double

    allow(User).to receive(:new).and_return(@user_instance)
    allow(@user_instance).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
    allow(@user_instance).to receive(:id).and_return(@user_id)

    post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}

    expect(response).to redirect_to(user_path(@user_id))
  end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Would it work to just use       'allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:id).and_return(1)' with my original test?

Comment: @Cu1ture yes, should work as well, in my example it's just more specific